# How to use Postgres 11 COPY command stdout stdin in stored procedure

Tags: postgresql

In Postgres 11 it is possible to `create procedure` not just functions, great! But we need to create a procedure to copy federated data without saving to disk using stdout/stdin.

Currently we use an "older" postgres extension called 'plsh' (it's unix code in plsh procedures). It works, but we are in middle of a process converting old code to the new Pg11 procedures.

In a plsh procedure we use it like this:

```
counter=$(${exec} "\copy (select * from  ${in_schemaname}.${in_tablename}) to   stdout ENCODING 'utf8'" | \
${exec} "copy ${in_schemaname}_backup.${in_tablename} from stdin" )  >/dev/null 2>&1;
```

We run into problems using `COPY` with stdout/stdin inside a new pg 11 procedure 
using PL/pgSQL.

Has anyone done this? Is it even possible?